# How to loop through multiple arrays within objects in a JSON API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, fetch-api

I have an API I'm trying to fetch and display data from. The data I want to access is in the 'equipments' array as shown below.

[image]

I'm trying to loop through the 'equipments' array for each item but I'm having trouble displaying the data. I believe I'm either not accessing it properly, or not including another loop somewhere.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// Fetch Data
function getData() {
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = "";
      data.groups.equipments.forEach(function(product) {
        output += `
          <div class="card">
            <img src=${product.photos.text} alt=${product.model} />
            <h3>${product.year} ${product.manufacturer} ${product.model}</h3>
            <p>${product.hours} hours</p>
            <a href='https://used.battlefieldequipment.ca/en/${product["group-code"]}/${product.equipments["serial-number"]}' class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
          </div>         
      `;
      });
      dataOutput.innerHTML = output;
    })
}

getData();
```

Any idea what I need to do in order to get this working?

Comment: `data.groups` is an array, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data.groups` is an array, you first have to iterate through them before accessing the `equipments`.

You can also iterate through them using a `forEach`, so that's easy!

```js
data.groups.forEach(function(group) {
  group.equipments.forEach(product) {
    output += `
          <div class="card">
            <img src=${product.photos.text} alt=${product.model} />
            <h3>${product.year} ${product.manufacturer} ${product.model}</h3>
            <p>${product.hours} hours</p>
            <a href='https://used.battlefieldequipment.ca/en/${product["group-code"]}/${product.equipments["serial-number"]}' class="btn btn-primary">View Details</a>
          </div>`;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of groups.equipments use

```
groups.map((g) => g.equipments)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the `equipments` property of the array. The property is in the object which is inside the array.

```js
data.groups.forEach(obj => {
  //obj.equipments is what you want now. It returns the equipments property of current object in the loop
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make twice forEach. Check here https://js.do/code/621480

Data groups is array also, so you have to take foreach group then foreach product in equipments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const loadApi = async () => {
    let url = await fetch(url)
    let res = await url.json();

    for (const element of res.groups) {
        for (const element2 of element.equipments) {
            getItemsFromProducts(element2);
        }
    }


}; loadApi();


const getItemsFromProducts = (data) => {
    let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
    demo.innerHTML = `
        <div id="product">
            <img src=${data.photos[0].text} alt=${data.model} />
            <h3>${data.year} ${data.manufacturer} ${data.model}</h3>
            <p>${data.hours} hours</p>
        </div>
    `;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.